# How do I create a Mongo config file to allow access to http on port 28017

Tags: mongodb, configuration, mongodb-3.0

Well I want to configure the mongo server to allows access for http.

I put this on my mongo config file:

```
port = 28017
rest = true
```

And when I restart my mongod service and try to access I got this message on the browser.

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native
>   driver port.

I check my logs:

```
cat /log/mongod.log
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20333 port=28017 dbpath=/data 64-bit host=ip-x-y-z-d
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] git version: 5901dbfb49d16eaef6f2c2c50fba534d23ac7f6c
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build18.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-08-07T18:07:27.430+0000 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true }, port: 28017 }, processManagement: { fork: true }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/data" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/log/mongod.log" } }
2015-08-07T18:07:27.434+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/journal
2015-08-07T18:07:27.434+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-08-07T18:07:27.778+0000 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 28017
2015-08-07T18:07:27.778+0000 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 29017
```

I refresh the browser and the logs show me that:

```
2015-08-07T18:24:09.246+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 181.196.26.130:64683 #24 (1 connection now open)
2015-08-07T18:24:09.246+0000 [conn24] end connection IPAddress:64683 (0 connections now open)
2015-08-07T18:24:09.493+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 181.196.26.130:53343 #25 (1 connection now open)
2015-08-07T18:24:09.493+0000 [conn25] end connection IPAddress:53343 (0 connections now open)
```

So If the log says that it waiting for connection on that port give me a respond but I can't see the http admin view, any idea or tips?

Answer (score 1):

You're on RHEL6 or a derivative from your kernel version `2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64`. The default firewall only allows ssh incoming. You'll need to poke a hole in your firewall. Look here for firewall tips:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Answer (score 1):

The `--port` parameter controls the base port that a `mongod` or `mongos` server listens to for TCP connections.

The HTTP interface is accessible at a port number that is 1000 greater than the base port, so given a `--port` of 28017 you can connect via port 29017 if you have enabled the HTTP interface.

You can see both ports listed in the server log on startup:

```
2015-08-07T18:07:27.778+0000 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 28017
2015-08-07T18:07:27.778+0000 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 29017
```

Note: the HTTP and REST interfaces do not include support for authentication and are unsuitable for production environments (they are disabled by default to prevent potential data exposure).

For more information, see [Network Exposure](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-network/) and [Security Checklist](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/) details in the MongoDB manual.